# ArgumentError in UsersController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have not changed my users_controller file, but now I am receiving this error after updating user profile "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)". It points to "app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41:in `update'".

My code looks to be right but I have to be missing something. Any ideas?

users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def profile
    @profile = User.profile
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def destroy
     User.find(params[:id]).destroy
     flash[:success] = "User deleted."
     redirect_to users_url
   end

def update
    @user = if current_user.role?(:admin)
       User.find(params[:id])
     else
       current_user
     end
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Account updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
end
```

Comment: According to your code, `@user = if current_user.role?(:admin)` is `line 41`, which you're passing a single, hard-coded Symbol to. I doubt that's the source of your error. How about providing more context around the error message itself?

Comment: And adding the `role?` method in your question would be good

Comment: What does that mean Zippie? I have the role? method in the first line.

Comment: Please add the definition of the `role?` method.

Comment: ah I need to add def roles to user.rb. Will keep you posted with how that goes. Thanks for the quick pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix for what I was having troubles with.

In user.rb I had to add:

```
  def has_role?(role_name)
    role.present? && role.to_sym == role_name.to_sym
  end
```

and then in the controller I just added:

```
 @user = if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
```

Before it was missing the **".has"** part to it.